# How to find a Perl module's version number though the command line on Unix?

Tags: perl, module, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of an installed Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135755/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-an-installed-perl-module)

I tried `perl -MMODULE -e 'print Thread::Semaphore';`, but it did not work! What is the right command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found something interesting I would like to share:

`perl -MThread::Semaphore\ 9999` It is a neat trick to find our version!!!

Comment: Wow, that's neat.  You should add "-e1" to the end, just in case the module has a version higher than what you put in, otherwise it hangs.  I knew about being able to use '-MThread::Semaphore=9999" and that this doesn't check VERSION, otherwise does normal importing, so a way around that is really quite helpful! :-)

Comment: The fact that this line generates some output on some systems on in some shells for some installed versions of a module does not make it a correct and useful answer.

Comment: @Tanktalus it doesn't hang, it just waits for the program to come in from STDIN. Just type Ctrl+D (on linux at least) and it will finish properly.

Comment: `perl -e 'use Thread::Semaphore 9999'` works with all shells the same way, of course adjusting the string delimiter for windows... doesn't change the fact that a module could have a version number that high, and sadly the parser does not dwim with something like 9**9**9, since it does not look like a simple number which is what the the compiler needs to interpret it as a version requirement.  And `Thread::Semaphore` itself seems to have a bug (at least in version 2.12) where it doesn't notice when you ask it to export something it does not have.  So an interesting, but not foolproof method...

Comment: @BradGilbert - I know.  I should have put "appears to hang" if you're not expecting it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the module has `$VERSION` defined (which is where the module version is canonically stored), this will get you the version:

```
perl -MModule -e 'print "$Module::VERSION\n";'
```

Comment: Canonically, VERSION is available as a class method; the default universal method checks the VERSION variable.

Comment: Putting ysth's comment into practical code: `perl -MModule -e 'print Module->VERSION'`

Comment: More chars, but you only have to change module name once `perl -we '$_=shift; eval "use $_; 1" and print $_->VERSION' Some::Module`

Comment: `perl -MModule -e 'die Module->VERSION'` is a little shorter

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -MThread::Semaphore -le 'print $Thread::Semaphore::VERSION'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pm_which`](http://p3rl.org/pm_which) to find out what version a module, or a list of modules are.

```
$> pm_which -mV Thread::Semaphore Thread
```

```
Thread::Semaphore [ 2.12 ]
Thread [ 3.02 ]
```

[`pm_which`](http://p3rl.org/pm_which) is a front end for [Module::Util](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aUtil), which has more methods for finding out about installed modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'eval {require Thread::Semaphore;print "Thread::Semaphore => ", $Thread::Semaphore::VERSION,"\n";}; print "\033[31mmissing Thread::Semaphore\033[0m\n";'
```

Here's what I had posted on [Find & Checking Modules Used by Perl Programs](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19220)