# How can I "require" a certain version of a Perl module?

Tags: perl, module, version

I have some Perl code that uses `require` instead of `use` to load a specific module, and I have just discovered that my code requires a minimum version on that module. However, unlike `use`, `require` does not seem to have a version argument when loading a module. So what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Related: *[How can I find the version of an installed Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135755)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call for `VERSION` method, it's inherited from the `UNIVERSAL` class. It checks for `$Module::VERSION` variable:

```
require Any::Module;
Any::Module->VERSION('2.3');
```

Comment: There is no point in using a `BEGIN` block if the original code doesn't have it.